# how does a dapp work on mist?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, mist, dapp-development, dapps

Ive made a dapp work on my system without a geth node working with metamask. The idea is that every user that comes up to the website has to spend his own gas for the transaction, so in metamask a popup comes up verifying the transaction gas. When I try to run this in Mist browser, no popup nothing comes up(no signing of transaction)..? and then no transaction actually takes place. How is it suppose to work in Mist?? Is the popup actually suppose to come up like metaamask? Will it even pick my web3 instance? It gives this error when I try to a transaction in Mist(runs fine with metamask)...[image]
Any help appreciated. thanks.